# How to get the key-value data of DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType object - override toString()?

Tags: java, paypal

I am implementing express checkout using `payPal::doExpressCheckoutPayment` and have a valid response from Paypal. But I want to save the complete response in a database table.

I am doing `doExpressCheckoutPaymentResponse.toString()`, but it is not giving me the key-value pair in the object.

> com.shaklee.rest.PayPalResource.doExpressCheckoutPaymentDetails() - urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType@3ba5113

is showing up.

How can I get the key-value representation of `doExpressCheckoutPaymentResponse`?

Comment: What class are you using?

Comment: @AndrewAngell: The class is 'DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType'. The full package is urn.ebay.api.PayPalAPI.DoExpressCheckoutPaymentResponseType